# How to add custom validation rule into laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I try to add new validation rule (Laravel 5.2) for google recaptcha and this rule not working. Can you explain me why? And how to fix it?

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('recaptcha', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return false;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

-

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'recaptcha|required',
        ]);
    }
```

Require rule working fine, recaptcha not.
I try to do dump-autoload - no results.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Did you [register your service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers#registering-providers)?

Comment: Try changing `return false` to `return $value == 'recaptcha'`

Comment: My new rule in AppServiceProvider and this provider already registered.

Comment: `return $value == 'recaptcha'` is worked for me, but this condition return false? why just false not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `recpatcha|required` to `captcha|required`

assuming you're using https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

Comment: I want to write my own script, but yes, already get a anhskohbo/no-captcha :)